# Xcode 9.2 Compiling So Slow

Tags: swift, xcode

I am currently using Xcode 9.2 with my MacBook Pro model. Since upgrading to Xcode 9.2 the compiling times takes forever. I'm testing my application on my iPhone not a simulator and I'm using sprite kit and swift 3. It shows "indexing | paused" and takes around 5 minutes to compile when it use to be 10 seconds before upgrading to 9.2.

If I close Xcode, unplug my iPhone and re-open Xcode and leave it for a few seconds then build, it builds in around 10 seconds. But then any build after that it takes forever again.

Please help, it's so hard to code with this much time wasted on building times.

Cheers :D

Comment: Sounds like the indexing "thing" struck you. Upgrades to either the iOS version on your device and/or Xcode means waiting until the indexing is done. Just grab a cup of coffee and read a (long) blog post and let Xcode do what it needs to do - index.

Comment: I wait for the indexing to be done. And its builds quickly. But then any other build after that, it takes forever again and says indexing paused again. Do I have to wait in-between builds before compiling?

Comment: That's not my experience. About 2 years ago I had this issue and needed to wait it out. Quitting Xcode didn't help. It just started the whole "indexing" process over. And each device meant the same thing. Two things - (1) Do things work fine in the simulator? (2) Have you (a) done a clean and project folder clean and (b) rebooted your Mac? For (2b) I've had some issues lately related to *old* projects getting build errors on a device **only**.

Comment: What is the Spec of your Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue when I was using the storyboard. You can try some small tweaks that helped me a lot and now its much better.

1. Try to off the "Automatically Refresh Views" from Editor.
2. Update your Xcode to the latest one which is much better and also if they don't Have it on the App Store, try getting it from the developer program from the iTunes connect.

hope this helps a little :)